# The function passed to the cron event doesn't do anything

Tags: php, wordpress, cron

I have this function actualizarwebinarsProximosARealizados() where I want to change the post term adding 'webinar-realizado' and removing 'webinar-proximo 'if the date condition is true but when the cron event is executed nothing happens.

This is the function code:

```
function actualizarwebinarsProximosARealizados() {
    // Obtener los posts que tienen la taxonomía "webinar"
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'formacion',
        'tax_query' => array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'tipo_evento',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => 'webinar',
            ),
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'tipo_evento',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => 'webinar-proximo',
            ),
        ),
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => 'fecha',
                'value' => date('Ymd'),
                'compare' => '<',
                'type' => 'DATE'
            ),
        ),
        'posts_per_page' => 50,
        'fields' => 'ids',
    );

    $webinars_proximos_clasificados = new WP_Query( $args );

    // Actualizar los términos de la taxonomía "tipo_evento" de los webinars realizados
    if ( $webinars_proximos_clasificados->have_posts() ) {
        $ids = $webinars_proximos_clasificados->posts;
        $taxonomy = 'tipo_evento';
        $terms_to_remove = 'webinar-proximo';

        wp_remove_object_terms( $ids, $terms_to_remove, $taxonomy );

        wp_set_object_terms( $ids, 'webinar-realizado', $taxonomy, true );
    }
}
```

And this is the code for the cron event:

```
add_action('init', 'agregar_taxonomia_a_webinars_condicional_cron');
function agregar_taxonomia_a_webinars_condicional_cron() {
    if (!wp_next_scheduled('agregar_taxonomia_a_webinars_condicional')) {
        wp_schedule_event(strtotime('today 3:00'), 'daily', 'agregar_taxonomia_a_webinars_condicional');
    }
    add_action('agregar_taxonomia_a_webinars_condicional', 'actualizarwebinarsProximosARealizados');
}
```

I've tried to query the posts and change the terms of them.

Comment: Does it work as intended if you execute it directly (for example by calling it in the functions.php, or inside a template), and not via cron?

Comment: It doesn't work in any place.

Comment: So what have you done so far to try and debut this then? Have you first of all verified that your query actually returns any posts?

Comment: Both `wp_remove_object_terms` and `wp_set_object_terms` take an integer as first parameter, according to the documentation - you appear to be passing an array.

Comment: That was the problem. I don't know how I couldn't see it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Both wp_remove_object_terms and wp_set_object_terms take an integer as first parameter, according to the documentation - you appear to be passing an array. –  CBroe

That was the problem with my code I created a loop for applying it too all the posts and now it works.

The code I changed:

```
    if ( $webinars_proximos_clasificados->have_posts() ) {
        $ids = $webinars_proximos_clasificados->posts;
        $taxonomy = 'tipo_evento';
        $terms_to_remove = 'webinar-proximo';

        foreach ( $ids as $post_id ) {
            wp_remove_object_terms( $post_id, $terms_to_remove, $taxonomy );
            wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, 'webinar-realizado', $taxonomy, true );
        }
    }
```